# Get subobject with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my view :

```
<span data-ng-init="fillEditForm['titi']='toto'" ></span>
```

In my controller Angular :

```
console.log($scope.fillEditForm);

console.log($scope.fillEditForm['titi']);
```

Result :

```
Object { titi: 'toto' }

undefined
```

I want to know how to directly access titi ?

I tried with dot ($scope.fillEditForm.titi), same result

Comment: Do not use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for initializing scope variables. `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.`... Controller will run before the ng-init updates the scope value. What happens when you do: `$scope.$evalAsync(function(){
    console.log($scope.fillEditForm.titi);    
  })` http://plnkr.co/edit/TmhcRZsGZuZNvPBrtvUz?p=preview

Comment: To add on `ng-init` has less priority than `ng-controller`

Comment: I use AngularJS with S2/ Twig in my project and I want to declare a variable in a template twig, there is another solution? Concretely, I want to recover the pre-fills form values ​​in edition to deal with AngularJS

Comment: Access it once it is set, try `scope.$evalAsync`, Did you check my previous comments? I dont know what is S2/Twig but ng-init is really not designed for this purpose.. You cannot initialize it in controller?

Comment: It doesn't work with $evalAsync. My fillEditForm variable is initialized in my controller Angular, I'm calling a form by AJAX then I would like to set Angular variable from form input in view.

Comment: Can you prepare a demo in a plnkr. Your pasted code has no relation to what you are saying now.

Comment: Plunkr not support Symfony framework (PHP), I tried to make a [diagram](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/197344Capturede769cran20141014a768181622.png) Thank you for your help, my problem is not easy to explain

Comment: You probably want to have the twig template write an angular module that contains the original data in a constant, this way the constant can be injected into other modules and they can get the data and everything stays relatively clean, still though I would question why you want to use server side templating I personally avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments a few times ng-init shouldn't be used for this case.  I've seen quite a few people do this type of thing where the template is being created with some data in it already, personally I think this just creates a mess and it's easier to just load the view then have it request data, typically the extra time needed is very small and you can show a loading message at least before the data is processed.

Anyhow opinion aside you can solve this using an angular constant being written by the twig template, I don't know the twig part so I'll pseudocode that

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  angular.module('serverData',[]).constant('SOME_DATA_SET', <?php echo json_encode($thing)?>);
</script>

//Meanwhile in Gotham
angular.module('myApp',['serverData']).controller(function($scope,SOME_DATA_SET){
  console.log(SOME_DATA_SET);
});
```